# Cannot update nor use pip in command prompt / PowerShell in Windows 10

Tags: ssl, pip

Always when I try to use pip this problem appears:

```
C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\NeuralNetworks>pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\eriku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

So here I just easily type in the command to upgrade/update pip, but somehow there's "no connection" /and SSL/HTML error, has anyone encountered similar problems? I tried installing TensorFlow but especially then it does not work. I run

```
-Windows 10
-16GB RAM
-2 Graphics Cards (One internal graphics [UHD Graphics 620] card and a normal card [GTX1050] )
-A quad-core CPU (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz)
```

I know it's a software issue but I'm still posting the hardware, it might help.

Just recently installed Linux and I'm double-booting, but this issue only occurs on Windows over here, Git Bash seems to work on both OS.
Docker Toolbox is successfully installed, Virtualization enabled, Python is installed... I can / used to be able to run python commands / I'm able to type "python" and then code in python in prompt, but not make any other python commands, very confusing.

```
C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\NeuralNetworks>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 17:13:21) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Don't worry about the Date, it's actually the 10th October 2019 at 11:02 AM, but.... I'm dual booting so ya know!

Happy for any help.

Comment: Please do not use tags that are unrelated to the problem. You are using PowerShell, not bash. Your problem has nothing to do with html or tensorflow.

Comment: Are you running this from your normal `cmd` or from the `anaconda prompt`? Please try the latter if not done already